# TapGestureRecognizer on Element with negative margin don't work

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem. I created an example project to solve it but I didn't succeed.
I created a button with a negative margin to be in the middle of the navigation bar.
The tap only works on the lower part.

**MainPage.xaml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage x:Class="HelloWorld.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Frame HeightRequest="56"
                   Margin="0"
                   Padding="0"
                   BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
            <Grid>
                <Frame WidthRequest="56"
                       HeightRequest="56"
                       Margin="0,-28,0,0"
                       Padding="0"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       VerticalOptions="Start"
                       BackgroundColor="Blue"
                       CornerRadius="28">
                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}" />
                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                </Frame>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Xamarin.Forms: 4.2.0.815419

[image: FAB]

Comment: Why do you use - margin. You can use navigation title view.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/navigation-titleview/

Comment: Try Margin="0, 0, 0, 56"

Comment: @sermet because I want a button over half an element.
I put an image that explains the design, but it's the tap that doesn't work well.

Comment: @DennisSchröer it doesn't work, but you allowed me to find the solution. Thank you.

Comment: @lsaudon Consider answering your own question to help other people who have might have the same question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="helloworld.MainPage">
    <Grid RowSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
        <Frame Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Padding="0">
        </Frame>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" TranslationY="-28">
            <Frame WidthRequest="56"
                    HeightRequest="56"
                    Margin="0"
                    Padding="0"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    BackgroundColor="Blue"
                    CornerRadius="28">
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped" />
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            </Frame> 
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: can you explain this?

Comment: @innom: what fixes the problem is moving the element wanting to float _up to its parent_, so that it's a sibling to the elements it wants to overlap. That is, instead of the inner Frame requesting -28, it's now the outer Grid. Don't be confused by the other fluff OP added (the empty ListView and Frame), or by the TranslationY attribute (things work even if you change this back to a Margin).

Comment: there is an issue: the gesture recognzier is not translating its values :( so you cannot click inside the button if you use negative values